# Usando Promise con Firebase JavaScript

Tags: javascript

en esta oportunidad llamo una base de datos en `firebase`, pero para darle un tiempo oportuno y asi estar casi segura que los datos estén cargados utilizo una `promise`con un `setTimeout` de la siguiente manera;

```js
  var  base = [];
  
  var promise = new Promise((res,err)=>{
      const db = firebase.database().ref().child('price');
      db.on('value', snap => base.push(snap.val()));

      setTimeout(res, 3000);
  });

  promise.then(()=>{
      console.log(base[0]);
  });
```

realmente soy algo novata con `JavaScrit` se que realmente no estoy asegurando que los datos ya esten en base al resolver la promesa, mi pregunta es como hacerlo? como hacer para saber que 'firebase' ya me ha retornado los datos.

gracias!

Comment: El evento `value` se gatilla varias veces? ¿Puedes loguear el contenido de `snap.val()`? ¿Que se loguea si usas en cambio `db.once('value',...`?